# error getting while start a value from 0 in auto increment

Tags: mysql

hi i have field UID in my mysql DB
 when i created table i used add UID int Primary key auto_increment so the value started from 1.So i deleted the field and created another time with out using primary key or auto_increment.then i inserted 0 and now when i want to make it primary and auto increment its not working.Please tell me how to do

```
alter table Patient add PRIMARY KEY(UID);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: @SJuan76 is right.Please check your table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a field primary key (or unique) if it already holds duplicated values. Check your records and get that there are no repeated UID values.